# How to read a csv file using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, intellij-idea

I'm working on a group project using IntelliJ, but my partners are using Eclipse. In IntelliJ I was able to place my csv files in my project folder and I am able to access them by just using the name of the file. However, my partners using eclipse are unable to use the csv files this way. The only way they have been able to is to type out the whole file location which obviously won't work if we are running the program on different computers. I don't have experience with eclipse is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default location for file I/O in Eclipse projects is in the root project directory. The Eclipse users will need to adjust their project settings so the default path is set to where yours is in your IntelliJ project.